# python regex, remove all except \d \s \w

Tags: python, regex

how to make a python RegEx which removes all characters form a text except the: `\d \w \s`

I tried something like this:

```
import re
re.sub(r'\W*\D*\S*', '', 'this is my<\n test <+-,1345.;>')
```

But this gives me a empty string. I want to get: `this is my test ,1234.`. I also would like to keep the `,` and `.`

Comment: Your character classes cancel each other out.

Comment: `\w` already includes `\d`, not need for explicit `\d` here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a inverted character class:

```
re.sub(r'[^., \t\w]*', '', 'this is my<\n test <+-,1345.;>')
```

Demo:

```
>>> re.sub(r'[^., \t\w]*', '', 'this is my<\n test <+-,1345.;>')
'this is my test ,1345.'
```

The `\W`, `\S` and `\D` classes are *too wide*. `\D` for example matches most of what `\w` matches, removing anything that falls in `\D` removes too much. Anything that is not a digit is to be removed, but you wanted to keep letters and punctiation.

I replaced `\s` with a literal space and a tab, because you want to remove newlines (also whitespace), and I added `.` and `,` so that those are kept too. `\d` is also not needed, `\w` is a superset of `\d`.

Comment: and how to remove the \n and keep the . and ,?

Comment: @gurehbgui: replace `\s` with a literal space and a `\t` tab (so remove the `\n` match) and add the punctuation to the inverted class too: `[^., \t\w\d]`